# How to change css styling of inline elements that are at default given in wordpress through external styling?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, css

```
<i class="Defaults-group tabs-icon tour_icon" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgb(16, 127, 201);" data-iconcolor="#107fc9" data-iconhovercolor="#ffffff" data-background="#107fc9"></i>
```

This is the code that is coming by default in my wordpress and I need to change this so that I could change the background color of the icons to green from the current blue icons. In short I need to change data-iconcolor and background from blue to green. But since it is in wordpress I'm unable to do it. Kindly help!

Comment: Considering how the styling is being set is it possible you can change the color in the backend settings? From the `data-*` attributes it looks like you might have a tough time tracking down everything you need to override.

Comment: what does it matter if it's in wordpress or not? Also suspect there is a script already parsing those data attributes and setting the inline styles

Answer (score 0):

Create a child theme. In the child theme edit the stylesheet with desired values. The child theme will override the theme. There are plug ins that are free and will create your child theme for you. The advantage of a child theme is that on update (wordpress or theme) you will not lose your customization.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the Styleoverride with "!important" parameter in your own CSS file that should be loading at the end.

```
.tabs-icon:hover, .tour_icon:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was trying but i actually need to change the styling while hovering.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know if it is helpfull